# Where has XamlPad gone in .NET 4.0 / Windows SDK v7.1 / Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I can't find **XamlPad** anywhere after I installed .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 SDK - v7.1.

I tried searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin
and did a `dir /s xamlpad.exe` to see if the Windows Index service didn't get to that folder yet.

And it's not under ***Start Menu -> All Programs -> Windows SDK v7.1 --> Tools***.

Where has it gone? Did MS deprecate it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It has been removed from the SDK (I think if you look in the release notes it'll say this, at least in v7.0), I've heard that XamlPadX or KaXaml could be suitable alternatives.

Comment: Installed .NET 4.5 and now KaXaml crashes on start-up. Too bad Microsoft discontinued XamlPad :-/